# Not sure why I am not moving through array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working on an assignment for class. I am to sort a deck of cards (don't need to worry about suits) I tried to make comments to explain it the best i could. I am trying to get the sort to work. It can only look at the first two cards and can swap them if you want and can move the top card to the bottom. I want the highest number at the front.

On about line 18 (my first for loop) what I was trying to do is loop through the array  using the for statement with int i. The nested for loop with int j is supposed to check the top two and if the top (index 0) is greater than the next (index 1) then it swaps the two so the greater is now at index 1 while the smaller is at index 0(the top) it then moves the top (the now smaller number) to the bottom making the larger number now at the top) and it does this as many times as there are numbers in the array minus 1. Then i advances and the top is now supposed to be at index 1 not index 0 and then it cycles though the nested loop again and so on and so forth. At least this is what I am trying to do.

Why is my loop not advancing through the array?

```
package algs21;
import stdlib.*;
// Exercise 2.1.14
/**
 * Complete the following method to sort a deck of cards,
 * with the restriction that the only allowed operations are to look
 * at the values of the top two cards, to exchange the top two cards,
 * and to move the top card to the bottom of the deck.
 */
public class MyDeckSort {
    public static void sort (MyDeck d) {
        // TODO
        // You must sort the Deck using only the public methods of Deck:
        //   d.size ();
        //   d.isSorted ();
        //   d.topGreaterThanNext ();
        //   d.swapTopTwo ();
        boolean notSorted=true;
while(notSorted){   
    notSorted=false;
    for (int i=0; i<d.size();i++){
        if (d.topGreaterThanNext()){
            d.moveTopToBottom();
            notSorted=true;
        }
        else{
            for(int j=0;j<d.size()-1;j++){
                if(!d.topGreaterThanNext()){
                    d.swapTopTwo();
                    d.moveTopToBottom();
                    notSorted=true;
                }
            }
            d.moveTopToBottom();
            notSorted=true;
        }
        //StdOut.printf ("i=%-3d %s\n", i, d.toString ());
    }
}
    private static double time;
    private static void countops (MyDeck d) {
        boolean print = true;

        if (print) StdOut.println (d.toString ());
        d.moveTopToBottom ();
        if (print) StdOut.println (d.toString ());
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch ();
        sort (d);
        time = sw.elapsedTime ();
        if (print) StdOut.println (d.toString ());
        d.isSorted ();
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int N = 10;
        MyDeck d = new MyDeck (N);
        countops (d);
        //System.exit (0); // Comment this out to do a doubling test!
        double prevOps = d.ops ();
        double prevTime = time;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            N *= 2;
            d = new MyDeck (N);
            countops (d);
            StdOut.printf ("%8d %10d %5.1f [%5.3f %5.3f]\n", N, d.ops (), d.ops () / prevOps, time, time / prevTime);
            prevOps = d.ops ();
            prevTime = time;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The Deck class has the following API:
 *
 * <pre>
 * MyDeck (int N)                 // create a randomized Deck of size N
 * int size ()                    // return the size of N
 * int ops ()                     // return the number of operations performed on this Deck
 * boolean topGreaterThanNext ()  // compare top two items
 * void swapTopTwo ()             // swap top two itens
 * void moveTopToBottom ()        // move top item to bottom
 * void isSorted ()               // check if isSorted (throws exception if not)
 * </pre>
 */
class MyDeck {
    private int N;
    private int top;
    private long ops;
    private int[] a;

    public long ops () {
        return ops;
    }
    public int size () {
        return N;
    }
    public MyDeck (int N) {
        this.N = N;
        this.top = 0;
        this.ops = 0;
        this.a = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = i;
        StdRandom.shuffle (a);
    }
    public boolean topGreaterThanNext () {
        int i = a[top];
        int j = a[(top + 1) % N];
        ops += 2;
        return i > j;
    }
    public void swapTopTwo () {
        int i = a[top];
        int j = a[(top + 1) % N];
        a[top] = j;
        a[(top + 1) % N] = i;
        ops += 4;
    }
    public void moveTopToBottom () {
        top = (top + 1) % N;
        ops += 1;
    }
    public String toString () {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder ();
        b.append ('[');
        for (int i = top;;) {
            b.append (a[i]);
            i = (i + 1) % N;
            if (i == top) return b.append (']').toString ();
            b.append (", ");
        }
    }
    public void isSorted () {
        boolean print = false;
        long theOps = ops; // don't count the operations require by isSorted
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            if (print) StdOut.printf ("i=%-3d %s\n", i, toString ());
            if (topGreaterThanNext ()) throw new Error ();
            moveTopToBottom ();
        }
        if (print) StdOut.printf ("i=%-3d %s\n", N, toString ());
        moveTopToBottom ();
        if (print) StdOut.printf ("i=%-3d %s\n", N + 1, toString ());
        ops = theOps;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your evidence that "the loop is not advancing through the array"?

Comment: My suggestion: Go to Wikipedia and look up "bubble sort".  Then adapt it to the assignment.  Ask yourself, how would you know when to stop?  You actually seem to be on the right track, but attempting to think about array indexes `i` and `j` is just confusing you, since you're not dealing with a typical array at all and you can't use indexes.

Comment: I think I am close with what I have just put up. The only thing is I want it to do my loops while it is not sorted. the isSorted method is void so i cant do while(!d.isSorted). So i have to figure that out. If I could do while(!d.isSorted) i think it would work.

Comment: Was it your idea to make `isSorted` a `void` method, or was it the instructor's?  If it's the instructor's, it is either a very bad idea or a wrench he threw in to make it more challenging.  You can use `isSorted` but you have to realize that it "returns" its result by using an exception.  You'll have to use a `try...catch` block to make use of it.

Comment: the instructor made it. I just created my own boolean variable "notSorted" and set it to true in my sort method. then wrapped the for loops in a while loop checking if notSorted is true which it is by default. The first thing it does is set notSorted to false.  Now i just have to figure out at what points do I set notSorted back to true. (i think)

Answer (score 0):

You're not dealing with arrays in this assignment - always just the pack top card. That card you can only either move to the bottom or switch with the next one. You need to think in terms of that. You don't need arrays here.

Edit: edited out my note about marker variable. You already have an isSorted() method so no need for that. After each iteration on the deck of cards, you need to check if you're sorted and exit the loop if you are.

Edit2: ok, if that method is void, this still applies:
You should have a marker variable when you cycle the cards in the pack that would you use to indicate something changed on that round. If nothing was changed, your pack is in order. If something was changed, you need to start another cycle.

Comment: I think I am close with what I have just put up. The only thing is I want it to do my loops while it is not sorted. the isSorted method is void so i cant do while(!isSorted). So i have to figure that out. If I could do while(!isSorted) i think it would work.

Comment: @iggyami ok. I wonder why it exists then :) but then you need the variable, yes.

Comment: ok so I added my own marker,  I am pretty sure im in an infinite loop though because i think no matter what ti does it sets notsorted to true. It could also just be taking a while. So i have to figure out where to put the notSorted=true and where I can remove from y current code. Am I on the right track though?

Comment: yep infinite loop for sure. Its sorting but then just cycles the numbers forever

Comment: Not sure if my answer is viable anymore. Ive tried setting the marker back to true in several different places only in one place and multiple places. All so far have given infinite loop, or it will run for a very long time. while it is sorted.

Comment: @iggyami do you have a deck of cards? :) it might be easier to visually experiment how the algorithm should go. You're doing it a bit too complicated. Basically, you have a pack with size n. you check if the card on the top is bigger than the next one, if it is, swap them around and set a variable saying something was changed. then move the card on the top to the bottom. Once you've done it n times, check if something was changed. If not, exit loop; if it was, reset variable and start again.